# My IDE is not recognizing Array.sort in Java

Tags: java, ide, netbeans-8

I think my IDE does not recognize Array.sort even though I did the import thing. I am using Java on Netbeans IDE 8.1. I am new to Java and programming please help.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] numbers2 = {31, 45, 22, 98, 10};
        Array.sort(numbers2); //there is an error here
        }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Change it to `Arrays.sort(numbers2);`